# Numeric field validation

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

I am new to Selenium, Can anybody explain the validation for numeric fields? I am struck in that validation. I want to validate a phone number field.

Comment: Selenium IDE or a language using the selenium bindings ?

Comment: IDE validation info at http://stackoverflow.com/q/5466031/631619

Comment: Programming example (java) at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12856036/textbox-restrictionsspecial-chars-numeric-etc-not-working-for-selenium-automat

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
A phone number field should take only numeric data and must have min and maxi length. Here we do following: (The below example includes script written in C#)

1. **Identify way to access field** - through ID/ Xpath/ Class...

E.g: - `IWebElement phoneNumberfield=   browser.FindElement(By.Id("txtPhoneNumber"));`

2. **Validate by entering a non-numeric input.**

   Try with alphabets then with special characters. Error should come on blur and/or on save.
   E.g:

   `phoneNumberfield.SendKeys("alpha");`

   `IWebElement inlineError = browser.FindElement(By.Path("\\span");`

(This you need to identify as every field will have an inline error space, and on save a big message may come on top/bottom of page)

```
bool isErrorShown=false;

if(inline.Text.Contains(ExpectedMsg)  //(ExpectedMsg should be like "Phone Number is invalid")

{

isErrorShown = true;

}

Assert.AreEqual(true,isFound);
```

(First parameter is expected result)

---This line should add pass/fail to your result excel.

3. **Validate by entering numeric input**. There should not be any error.

```
phoneNumberfield.SendKeys("9032350749");
if(inline.Text.Contains(ExpectedMsg) //( ExpectedMsg should be like "Phone Number is invalid")
{
isErrorShown = true;
}
Assert.AreEqual(false,isFound); //(First parameter is expected result which is false because there should not be any error)
```

---This line should add pass/fail to your result excel.

4. **Validate minimum length for input** -Enter input less than 8-10(depending on standard minimum phone number length).  Error should come on blur and/or on save.

```
phoneNumberfield.SendKeys("232");

if(inline.Text.Contains(ExpectedMsg)  //(ExpectedMsg should be like "Phone Number is invalid")

{

isErrorShown = true;

}

Assert.AreEqual(true,isFound); (First parameter is expected result)
```

---This line should add pass/fail to your result excel.

4. **Validate maximum length of input** - Enter input exceeding 10 digits. Field should stop accepting input after 10 chars.

```
bool MaxLengthCheck = false;

phoneNumberfield.SendKeys("90323507499");

if(phoneNumberfield.GetAttribut("value").Count ==10)

{

MaxLengthCheck = true;

}

Assert.AreEqual(true,MaxLengthCheck); //(First parameter is expected result)
```

---This line should add pass/fail to your result excel.

- Some of the above steps can be removed if few of these validations are not generic in nature based on the requirement of the form you are automating.

NOTE: Different approach may be followed to validate pass/fail results.Instead of messages, you can set different criteria to finalize your test result.

Thanks. I hope the above steps helps you.

Answer (score 1):

It may help break this question into three parts, as follows.

**How do I manually test validation for a phone number field?**

Trying Googling for phrases like "phone number validation" or "phone number syntax".  Conventions for phone numbers vary by country; see for example [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_conventions_for_writing_telephone_numbers).

**How do I manually test fields in a user interface?**

If you can't answer this, you might try talking with someone in your company who manually tests user interfaces for a living.  This is too broad of a subject to answer here.  You might also try buying a book on manual testing or Googling for "testing field validation".

**How do I test field values in Selenium?**

This boils down to setting a field value, taking an action that causes the field value to be processed (e.g. submitting the form), and then checking whether the action produced the expected results.